# Why an EnumSet or an EnumMap is likely to be more performant than their hashed counterparts?

Tags: java, enums, enumset, enum-map

The following is from the *Implementation Note* section of [Java doc of EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) :

> Implementation note: All basic operations execute in constant time.
>   They are likely (though not guaranteed) to be faster than their
>   HashMap counterparts.

I have seen a similar line in the java doc for `EnumSet` also . I want to know why is it more likely that `EnumSets` and `EnumMaps` will be more faster than their hashed counterparts ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`EnumSet` is backed by a bit array. Since the number of different items you can put in `EnumSet` is known in advance, we can simply reserve one bit for each enum value. You can imagine similar optimization for `Set<Byte>` or `Set<Short>`, but it's not feasible for `Set<Integer>` (you'd need 0.5 GiB of memory for 2^32 bits) or in general.

Thus basic operations like `exists` or `add` ar constant time (just like `HashSet`) but they simply need to examine or set one bit. No `hashCode()` computation. This is why `EnumSet` is faster. Also more complex operations like union or easily implemented using bit manipulation techniques.

In OpenJDK there are two implementations of `EnumSet`: `RegularEnumSet` capable of handling enum with up to 64 values [in `long`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/RegularEnumSet.java#RegularEnumSet.0elements) and `JumboEnumSet` for bigger enums (using [`long[]`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/JumboEnumSet.java#JumboEnumSet.0elements)). But it's just an implementation detail.

`EnumMap` works on similar principles, but it uses `Object[]` to store values while key (index) is implicitly inferred from `Enum.ordinal()`.

Comment: A bit can have only a 0 or 1 . So how would the EnumSet represent a set that contains four Enum values ?

Comment: @Geek: say you have `enum Foo {A, B, C, D, E}`. `EnumSet` will keep a bit array of 5 bits. If this set represent `A`, `B` and `D`,the bit array will be: `11010`.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumSet` uses array[] inside and a natural order with consequent consequences:

- **fast**: get/set is called by constant time O(1), `hashCode()` is not used to find a right bucket
- **memory efficiency**: the size of array is predefined by Enum size and is not dynamic

`EnumMap` uses Enum as a key based on the same principals as `EnumSet` where hash code collision is not possible