# How EnumMap fail safe though it is not syncronized

Tags: java, enum-map

I am working on EnumMap  and i want to why know it is fail safe though none of the methods of EnumMap is synchronized.

I am not taking iterator on key set but using for each loop

```
 public class JavaEnumMapExample {

  public enum MealType {
    BREAKFAST, LUNCH, SNACK, DINNER
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<MealType, String> myMealMap = new EnumMap<MealType, String>(MealType.class);

    // populate the map
    myMealMap.put(MealType.BREAKFAST, "Enjoy Milk and Eggs for breakfast!");
    myMealMap.put(MealType.LUNCH, "Enjoy Chicken, Rice and bread for Lunch!");
    myMealMap.put(MealType.SNACK, "How about an apple for the evening snack!");
    myMealMap.put(MealType.DINNER, "Keep the dinner light, lets have some salad!");

    System.out
            .println("Welcome to meal planner, we have suggestions for following meals : ");

    // print all the keys of enum map in sorted order
    System.out.println(myMealMap.keySet());

    // We can get the value from enumType
    System.out.println(" Q: What should I have for lunch? ");
    System.out.println(" A: " + myMealMap.get(MealType.LUNCH));

    System.out.println(" Q: What should I have for snack? ");
    System.out.println(" A: " + myMealMap.get(MealType.SNACK));

    System.out.println(" Q: What should I have for dinner? ");
    System.out.println(" A: " + myMealMap.get(MealType.DINNER));

    // Iterate over enumMap
    for (MealType mealType : myMealMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(myMealMap.get(mealType));
    }
    System.out.println("*** Checking for concurrent modification exception! ***");
    // Does not throw Concurrent modification Exception in enumMap
    for (MealType mealType : myMealMap.keySet()) {
        if (MealType.SNACK.equals(mealType)) {
            myMealMap.remove(MealType.SNACK);
        }
    }

    // map changed without throwing Concurrent modification Exception
    System.out.println(myMealMap);

}

  }
```

Can some one tell me why it is fail safe?

Comment: Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: In the map.keySet docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) we can read:
"If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined"

Comment: actually foreach loop for set using iterator behind the scene, so you cannot say you are not using iterator for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see EnumMap.java source and in comments givent that Iterators returned by the collection views are **weakly consistent**: they will **never throw ConcurrentModificationException** and they may or may not show the effects of any modifications to the map that occur while the iteration is in progress.

One more aspect given at [EnumMap Performance Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536665/why-an-enumset-or-an-enummap-is-likely-to-be-more-performant-than-their-hashed-c/14536699#14536699)