# XOR toggle an Enum value in or out of an EnumSet

Tags: java, enumset

I am refactoring some code that used low-level bit manipulation and masking to reimplement it with an `EnumSet`. The incentive is: having a much more maintainable and readable code. I find it appropriate to abstract the logic away from low-level implementation like bits and memory units, while trading some minor efficiency loss (if any).

I already wrote the base methods to set, unset various states to replace bits. But I also need a method to flip a flag (set if unset, unset if set).

Here is a simplified subset of my class. It handles the state of input restriction per side of a block in a MinecraftForge mod (if context matters). Most of the time, player interacts with the setting of the side restriction, to flip it one way or the other (thus using the `flip()` method).

```java
public class InputRestrictor {

    protected EnumSet<ForgeDirection> sideRestricted = EnumSet.noneOf(ForgeDirection.class);

    public void set(final ForgeDirection side, final boolean isInputOnly) {
        if (isInputOnly) sideRestricted.add(side);
        else sideRestricted.remove(side);
    }

    public boolean get(final ForgeDirection side) {
        return sideRestricted.contains(side);
    }

    public void flip(final ForgeDirection side) {
        set(side, !get(side));
    }
}
```

I think if the `EnumSet` had a native method to flip an enum value in-out of the set, it would be more efficient than first fetching the boolean state, inverting it and setting it or removing it conditionally.

I read in this post [Why an EnumSet or an EnumMap is likely to be more performant than their hashed counterparts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14536665/7939871), an EnumSet is internally implemented using a bit-mask or bit-field. Would be convenient if one could just toggle XOR one or more enum values (in or out of the set) in one step like you'd do with:

```java
byte bits = 0b000111;
bits ^= (byte) 1 << 2; // inverted bit 2: bits = 0b00011
bits ^= (byte) 0b111111; // inverted all at once: bits = 0b111100
```

Are there more direct toggling methods beside going low level with bit manipulation?

Comment: A little wonky, but how about: `if (!sideRestricted.remove(side)) { sideRestricted.add(side); }`. You want to avoid iterating the set to find it, but unless you extended the class I don't think there's a direct swap available. Note that operations on `EnumSet` are _extremely_ fast (it's bit logic on a `long` using `Enum#ordinal`, so extending would avail you that ability).

Comment: To do the bit flip in the case of extending, you'd want `this.set ^= yourEnumConstant.ordinal()`, where `this.set` would be the bitfield/`long` held by `EnumSet`. Note even with the direct bit manipulation, there's still at least the three read-update-write operations. Compound assignment operators are not atomic, so (slightly) not thread safe here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `EnumSet` only exposes the basic `Set` methods, which do not include a toggle of the form you describe.

I would suspect that the reason it does not provide such a method is that it would be very rarely used.  Most usages of Sets -- certainly those that'd require high performance -- seem likely to only need to add and remove.

Answer (score 0):

Given my requirements to abstract away from the implementation, keep decent performances and [Louis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76096912/7939871) confirming the absence of toggling in the `EnumSet` implementations; There is a good middle-ground for my use case.

The implementation details can be moved away from the main class, while still flipping bits.

I found it out when I realised my abstraction could be reused for other kind of enumerated boolean properties packed into a binary number, where those also need a byte representation of the sided boolean state : to transmit, save and load persistent data in a minimal byte space.

Rewrote it this way:

```java
public class EnumBoolean<T extends Enum<T>> {

    public long bits = 0;

    public void set(final T enumValue) {
        bits |= (1L << enumValue.ordinal());
    }

    public void clear(final T enumValue) {
        bits &= ~(1L << enumValue.ordinal());
    }

    public void setBoolean(final T enumValue, final boolean boolValue) {
        if (boolValue) set(enumValue);
        else clear(enumValue);
    }

    public boolean get(final T enumValue) {
        return (bits & (1L << enumValue.ordinal())) != 0;
    }

    public void toggle(final T enumValue) {
        bits ^= (1L << enumValue.ordinal());
    }
}
```

Then the byte bit state can be obtained by casting, saved and reloaded very efficiently.

If I had persisted with the `EnumSet` it would have required looping through values, turn it to bit and the other way to load. Or worse overkill implementation with a `BitSet` of the persistence byte, which uses and returns an array. (way too much bloat for 6-bits). I examine the `RegularEnumSet` implementation, and while switching bits internally, it also contains lots of boilerplate, type testing and checks that are useless bloat for this use case.

```java
EnumBoolean<ForgeDirection> disabledInput = new EnumBoolean<>();

// yada yada yada

public void saveNBTData(final NBTTagCompound nbtTagCompound) {
   nbtTagCompound.setByte("disabledInput", (byte) disabledInput.bits);
}

public void loadNBTData(final NBTTagCompound nbtTagCompound) {
    disabledInput.bits = nbtTagCompound.getByte("disabledInput");
}
```

Comment: You can change `ForgeDirectionBoolean` to `CustomEnumSet<T extends Enum<T>>`, and `ForgeDirection` to `T`, and you've basically got just that: your very own `EnumSet` class.

Comment: @Rogue, thank you so much. I genericized it to your recommendation and now I can reuse it for many kinds of Enumerated booleans of up to 64 values. Which is overkill but leave plenty of margin in my use case.